# collision point of circle and line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, intersection-theory

I'm trying to figure out the collision point of the circle and a line, ultimately it should work in 3D but for now just in 2D to simplify the problem as much as possible.

I've created 2 examples here on what I'm trying to achieve, I want to find point **B** and **D** and it should work both the examples below.

**PS. this problem is probably harder to solve than it initially looks like.**

Example 1:
[image: example1]

//edit
Radius = 50;

A.x = 70

A.y = 100

B.x = ?

B.y = ?

C.x = -60

C.y = -70

D.x = ?

D.y = ?

E.x = -200

E.y = 0

F.x = 200

F.y = 0

AC_vector = [-130, -170]  ---> (= C-A = [((-60)-70), ((-70)-100)] )

AC_distance = 214.009 ---> = √((A.x - C.x)^2 + (A.y - C.y)^2)  = sqrt((70 - -60)^2 + (100 - -70)^2)

AC_vectorN = [-0.607451, -0.794359] ---> = AC_vector/AC_distance = [-130/214.009, -170/214.009] // AC_vector normalized

EF_vector = [400, 0]  ---> = ( E-F = [(200-(-200)), ((0-0)] )

EF_distance = 400 ---> = √((E.x - F.x)^2 + (E.y - F.y)^2)  = sqrt((-200 - 200)^2 + (0 - 0)^2)

EF_vectorN = [1, 0] ---> = EF_vector/EF_distance = [400/400, 0/400] // EF_vector normalized

N = [0, 1] // (surface normal) perpendicular vector of normalized EF

Example 2
[image: example 2]

Solution:

Edit// This is what I have figured out so far:

- The distance between B and D is always the radius (50)
- The vector of BD is the normal of EF (90deg rotaition of EFvector)
- So B = D + N*R?

Last part of the solution can be found here:
[right triangle in 3D space, vectors, line intersection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603556/right-triangle-in-3d-space-vectors-line-intersection/1603617#1603617)

And here is the result of the solution:
https://youtu.be/1MiwtA329tQ

[image: solution_02]

Comment: What is a `collision point` of a circle and a line?

Comment: @Bernard that would be point D in my example images, the reason I call it collision point is because I'm going to use it for a physics engine , and point A is the current position and point C is the projected position after the velocity have been applied and if it detect an intersection then I want to figure out where it collided (point D) so I can place it at the correct position (point B) before I reflect the velocity etc.

Comment: Do you have the equations of line and circle at any point in time? Do you have the circle path time line? I can envision at least two ways to solve this. Do you assume that the line is y=0? What is r of the circle?

Comment: Looks like B coordinates are (?,r) - right?

Comment: @Moti all the values I have are in the two images the radius is 50 its in the green circle, I just forgot to add it in the text,  when i'm actually implementing it I have acces to a lot of functions so alot of these values I dont have to calculate like the normal of the EF line i just get that by raytracing and have functions for normalizing etc

Comment: @Moti The B coordinates I dont know yet thats part of what I'm trying to calulate, in the example 1 x pos is easy because yeah its simply the radius of the circle but the same formula need to work on both the example 1 and 2

Comment: Small point: Instead of saying circle it might be clearer to say disc?

Comment: @Paul maybe I just tought the images would clearify any confusions.

Comment: What is the radius of the disc?

Comment: @Moti its 50 units of your choice

Comment: Find the equations of the 2 lines. Than find an equation of a line perpendicular to the target line. Find the intersection of the target and perpendicular. Find a line parallel to target at distance r. The intersection of this line with the disc path line is the desired center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the picture that complements the comment. Thought this could help.
Point G (red) is the center of the disc at collision. remember to select the proper collision point - there are two.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, tough not sure that I solved it 100% like the way you sugested but either way your solution help me to get to my final solution, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equation of a line passing through two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$

$$ (y_1-y_2) x + (x_2-x_1) y + (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 ) = 0 $$

A parallel offset to this line with a perpendicular distance $d$ is

$$ (y_1-y_2) x + (x_2-x_1) y + \left(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 -d \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2} \right) = 0$$

All you need to do is find the offset line to *EF* that passes through the center of the circle. This is done by offsetting with the circle radius amount

[image: pic]

Then you have two lines that you need to find where they intersect. If the offset line is $A x+ B y + C =0$ and the *CA* line is $P x + Q y + W = 0$ then their intersection is located at

$$ (x,y) = \left( \frac{B\, W-C\, Q}{A\, Q-B\, P}, \frac{C\, P-A\, W}{A\, Q-B\, P} \right) $$

<sub>NOTE: If the denominator is zero the lines are parallel</sub>

So the process is

1. Use the first equation to find the coefficients $(P,Q,W)$ for the line *AC*
2. Use the second equation to find the coefficients $(A,B,C)$ for the line *EF* and offset $d=\mbox{(radius)}$
3. Use the third equation to find the coordinates for the center of the circle.

Comment: Thanks, tough I were able to solve it just a few minutes earlier, but thanks anyways this information will be usfull in the future (: